# mysql getting average of client per day in a month

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT COUNT(client_ID) / DAY(LAST_DAY(dateRequested))
FROM `tbl_client`
WHERE dateRequested BETWEEN  DATE_FORMAT(dateRequested,'%Y-%m-01') AND LAST_DAY(dateRequested)
```

I want to show the average of client per day in the month

```
client_ID   |   dateRequested
   1        |   2018-07-04
   2        |   2018-07-05
   3        |   2018-07-06
   4        |   2018-07-07
   5        |   2018-08-04
   6        |   2018-08-06
   7        |   2018-08-09
```

i want to show

```
Average  |     Month
4        |   July 2018
3        |   August 2018
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS Average, DATE_FORMAT(dateRequested, '%M %Y') FROM tbl_client GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(dateRequested, '%M %Y')` ... this would seem to generate the exact output you showed.

Comment: Your example is unclear. What happens if the person with `client_ID` = 1 visits on more than one day? Should that count as one visitor or two?

Comment: Awesome! thankyou!

Comment: How about per day?

Comment: To get data by day, just change `DATE_FORMAT(dateRequested, '%M %Y')` in @TimBiegeleisen query to `dateRequested`

Comment: The desired result you posted doesn't contain the average per day in the month (which would be 4/31 and 3/31 I believe) but the count of the month. What do you really want?

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
SELECT COUNT(client_ID),concat(month(dateRequested),year(dateRequested)) 
FROM `tbl_client`
WHERE dateRequested BETWEEN  DATE_FORMAT(dateRequested,'%Y-%m-01') AND LAST_DAY(dateRequested)
group by concat(month(dateRequested),year(dateRequested))
```